# Replacing Nulls for one Variable based off another

Tags: r, replace, missing-data, categorical-data, imputation

I have a dataset consisting of measured variables and categorical variables based off these measurements. i.e X1 is measured variable and Y1 will either be 0 or 1 based off the measurement in X1.

There was a lot of Null values in the X1 variable, which I have replaced already. I am now trying to replace the corresponding Y1 variable based off the new value in X1.

So what I'm trying to do with the below code is say if there is a Null in Y1, check if the corresponding X1 value is less than 34.5. If so give that Y1 0, otherwise 1.

```
Data$Y1[is.na(Data$Y1)] <- ifelse(Data$X1 <34.5, 0, 1)
```

Error i get:
Warning message:
In x[...] <- m :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Without a reproducible example, this is just a guess:  when you replace the NA Y1's, you need only use the X1's where Y1 is NA: `Data$Y1[is.na(Data$Y1)] <- ifelse(Data$X1[is.na(Data$Y1)] <34.5, 0, 1)`

Comment: That seems to have done the trick Dan. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

a simple loop should do the trick

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Data){
  if (is.na(Data$Y1[i])==TRUE){
    Data$Y1[i] <- ifelse(Data$X1[i] <34.5, 0, 1)
  }
}
```

It may not be the most sufficient way but the logic is pretty clear and runs fairly fast when your dataset isn't huge